# Auth::check returns null when I set a guard

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a multi-auth in Laravel 5.8, but I'm facing a problem. When I set a guard on my **auth::attempt**, login is done successfully, but **auth::check** and **auth::user** return false and null respectively.

It only works when I change default guard in my config/auth.php to my custom-guard.

`'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],`

To:

`'defaults' => [
            'guard' => 'clients',
            'passwords' => 'users',
        ],`

I'd like to use a lot of guards, not just one. And whenever I need to, return their data with Auth::user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you also need to specify a guard when calling Auth::check/user - for example:

```
Auth::guard('yourGuard')->check()
```